# How Do I Nest HTML Fragments (Partials) in Meteor?

Tags: html, meteor, spacebars

Is there any way to nest partials (fragments of HTML) in Meteor?

Why can't I say

```
<template name="foo">hello world!</template>
<template name="bar">{{> foo}}</template>
<template name="baz">{{> bar}}</template>
```

?

This is a very common thing to do in any HTML page, and it's a regular feature of Mustache and Handlebars. Why does Meteor fail silently when I try this?

Comment: Create a new project, add your code to the bottom of the .html file, add `{{> baz}}` to the main template. Everything works as expected. I suspect something else is going on with your code.

Comment: You can... They do it in every one of the [examples](http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard). You have to put your top level template inside the body template: `<body>{{> baz}}</body>`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what sbking means ...

the leaderboard example has a single leaderboard.html file
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/leaderboard/leaderboard.html

```
<head>
  <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    {{> leaderboard}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
  <div class="leaderboard">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>

  ...
</template>

<template name="player">
  ...
</template>
```

But this can be divided into many files since meteor looks at all of them.  for example

leaderboard.html would have

```
<template name="leaderboard">
  <div class="leaderboard">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  ...
</template>
```

and player.html would have

```
<template name="player>
   ...
</template>
```

and it would still work!!!! black magic!

Answer (score 0):

The full Meteor documentation provides a couple of great, simple examples of this, which can be found in [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/livehtmltemplates) section, with some additional useful information to get you started as well. Basically, the only thing that you need to make sure you do is have your top-level template contained within the `<body>` tag like so:

```
<body>
    {{> a}}
</body>

<template name="a">
    Top-Level Template
</template>
```

Then, you can nest as deep as you would like from there on down to your deepest template:

```
<template name="a">
    Top-Level Template
    {{> b}}
</template>

<template name="b">
    Mid-Level Template
    {{> c}}
</template>

<template name="c">
    ...
</template>
```

Also, your templates do not need to be defined in the same HTML file as your `<body>` definition. They can all be defined in the same file or separated into a different file for each template (which becomes much more of a good idea once your templates become sufficiently large and complex).